# Приведение типов из object

Tags: java, преобразование-типов

Доброго времени суток.
В методе equals не работает приведение типов. В чем проблема?

```
class Pair<T, U>
 {
     private T first;
     private U second;
     public Pair()
     {
        first = null;
        second = null;
    }
    public Pair(T f, U s)
    {
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }
    public void setFirst(T arg)
    {
        first = arg;
    }
    public void setSecond(U arg)
    {
        second = arg;
    }
    public T getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }
    public U getSecond()
    {
        return second;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return first.toString()+" "+second.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass()!=other.getClass())
            return false;
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        Pair<T,U> Other = (Pair<T,U>) other; //эта строка не работает
        if (getFirst().equals(Other.getFirst())&&getSecond().equals(Other.getSecond()))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return 3*getFirst().hashCode()-4*getSecond().hashCode();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Не компилируется или работает не корректно?

Comment: у меня все работает корректно. что у вас не так? опишите подробно ошибку

Comment: Не компилируется

Comment: Unchecked cast.

Comment: Ide dcoder на андроиде

Comment: @Shilko2013 попробуйте ` Pair<?, ?> pair = (Pair<?, ?>) other;`

Comment: Это не ошибка, это предупреждение(warning). Видимо у нас стоят настройки считать предупреждения ошибками. Вам либо изменить эту настройку, либо исправить его, в вашем случае надо добавить проверку что класс именно тот(через instanseof).

Comment: Добавил instanceof теперь пишкт что объявление переменной здесь невозможно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще то, конструкция вида

```
Pair<T,U> Other = (Pair<T,U>) other;
```

не является корректной, т.к. в райнтайме дженерики стираются. Вместо `U`, `T` у полей будет тип `Object`. Естественно компилятор пытается предупредить вас о возможной ошибке. Но вы можете проверить, является ли данный объект типом `Pair`, а затем проверить каждое поле на равенство либо, сопоставимость типов:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null)
            return false;
    if (this == other)
            return true;

    if (!(other instanceof Pair))
            return false;

    Pair<?, ?> obj = (Pair<?, ?>) other; 
    if (Objects.equals(obj.first, this.first) && Objects.equals(obj.second, this.second))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Но если вы точно знаете и совершенно уверены в том, что делаете то аннотация `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` для вас. Она избавляет от этих назойливых предупреждений во время компиляции.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (other != null && other instanceof Pair) {
        Pair<?,?> otherPair = (Pair<?,?>) other;
        if (otherPair.getFirst() istanceof T && otherPair.getSecond() instaceof U) {
            T otherFirst = (T)otherPair.getFirst();
            U otherSecond = (U)otherPair.getSecond();
            result = first.equals(otherFirst) && second.equals(otherSecond);
        }
    } 
    return result;
}
```